# Can I keep this tree without it destroying my fence?

Tags: trees, pruning, fence

I have an unplanned (privet?) tree growing right at the base of a fence. It's currently around 15' tall at the peak, but not particularly wide.

I don't dislike this tree, except for the danger to the fence. Is there anything I can do to keep it without it eventually damaging the fence?

[image]

Comment: you can give your fence several years by pulling it away more, and doing an espalier to the tree

Answer (score 3, accepted):

not really, it is coming from right below the fence...

if you want to keep it you would want to wait for the plant to go dormant if you are in a temperate climate (looks like a ficus and the tree in the background is a palm, so probably not), then prune it back to have minimal foliage, and then dig it out as carefully as possible and replant it somewhere...

Comment: Yes, that’s a palm. N California